# Different header/footer for guest users

Tags: magento2, layout

I want to show different header and footer for the guest users and default one for the logged-in users.

What is the right way to do so ?

AND using the custom module to achieve this.

Comment: Did you try https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/cache/page/private-content/?

Comment: no but i want to create different phtml templates for each header and footer in the custom module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

1/ In your block, need to add Customer Group identifier to cache key.

2/ `layout_load_before` observer event. Put this event under frontend scope. In your observer, add your layout handle with your conditions.

```
$layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
$layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('your_custom_handle_layout');
```

Comment: so this will not affect full page cache..right ? as i don't want to mess up with the caching.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) it worked :)